# getchar() avoid escape sequences

Tags: c++, console-application, getchar

I'm writing Linux console application (some kind of a menu) and so I need to get input from a user. Here is a code I used so far:

```cpp
int getch(void)
{
    int ch;
    struct termios oldt;
    struct termios newt;
    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &oldt);
    newt = oldt;
    newt.c_lflag &= static_cast<unsigned int>(~(ICANON | ECHO));
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newt);
    ch = getchar();
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldt);
    return ch;
}

#define KEY_UP 65
#define KEY_DOWN 66
#define KEY_ESC 27

while(true)
{
    ch = getch();

    switch(ch)
    {
        case KEY_UP:           
            break;
        case KEY_DOWN:
            break;
        case ESC:
            break;
    }
}
```

Everything was fine until I needed to use ESC. Suddenly it turned out that getch() sometimes returns several integers in the loop. For example:

```
KEY_UP:   27 91 65
KEY_DOWN: 27 91 66
BKSPACE:  127
ESC:      27
```

Ok, in my case I will get the right value (for example 65 for KEY_UP) after 3 iterations in the loop but how can I get ESC when I really click the Esc button?
How can I configure the getch() to return only real value and avoid the esc sequences?

Ubuntu 18.04
gcc 7.4.0
libstdc++.so.6

Comment: 65 is *not* 'the right value for KEY_UP'. It's simply the same as the letter 'A' (ASCII 0x41 = 65 decimal)

Comment: Keyboards can contain more keys than there are numbers in a 7-bit integer (which is the "standard" since very long ago). Therefore some keys needs to use multiple numbers to distinguish themselves. How else would e.g. `65` for key up differ from the number `65` for the letter `'A'` (assuming ASCII)?

Comment: exactly! I know that 65 is not the right key. I've just put it for compatibility with getch() output. But how can I separate between the Up key (which starts from 27) and real Esc key (which also starts from 27)?

Comment: There is no difference. The only way to have an idea is whether or not the escape is followed by a valid escape sequence.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the real ESC key implementing a `kbhit` function, basically `kbhit` returns true if there is more data pending to be read in the buffer, here `kbget` is a wrapper returning the result of your `getch` or `KEY_ESCAPE` (27):

```
static int kbhit(void)
{
    int c = 0;

    tcgetattr(0, &oterm);
    memcpy(&term, &oterm, sizeof(term));
    term.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO);
    term.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
    term.c_cc[VTIME] = 1;
    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &term);
    c = getchar();
    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &oterm);
    if (c != -1) ungetc(c, stdin);
    return ((c != -1) ? 1 : 0);
}

static int kbesc(void)
{
    int c;

    if (!kbhit()) return KEY_ESCAPE;
    c = getch();
    if (c == '[') {
        switch (getch()) {
            case 'A':
                c = KEY_UP;
                break;
            case 'B':
                c = KEY_DOWN;
                break;
            case 'C':
                c = KEY_LEFT;
                break;
            case 'D':
                c = KEY_RIGHT;
                break;
            default:
                c = 0;
                break;
        }
    } else {
        c = 0;
    }
    if (c == 0) while (kbhit()) getch();
    return c;
}

static int kbget(void)
{
    int c;

    c = getch();
    return (c == KEY_ESCAPE) ? kbesc() : c;
}
```